# Drupal error while installing

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

Hello guys I'm new to drupal! I install drupal 8.5.1. After installing this error message will be thrown.

> Error: Call to a member function setRecipients() on null in standard_form_install_configure_submit() (line 25 of core\profiles\standard\standard.profile).

See the error [here](https://ibb.co/b73Aex).

Comment: Please provide more information about your problem.

Comment: Have a read of the issues [HERE](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2780071)